# Question on sUAS course in lieu of knowledge test for Part 61 certificate holders

Tags: faa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

If I am a PPL already, it appears that you can just take a course and pass a quiz to satisfy requirements for part 107 as such:

"If you are a part 61 pilot certificate holder and you have a current flight review (per 14 CFR part 61.56), successful completion of this course is your ONLY training and testing requirement. At the end of this course, complete the online knowledge check (exam) and print your completion certificate."

Now, I received my PPL in August 2019 and my IR on August 2020, and I know that both reset the clock on flight review requirements. However, since they specify flight review in the requirement, do I really need one or do the oral/checkrides for the ratings count as part of that review?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking. The title of your question doesn’t seem to match the body. Are you asking if the 107 requirement for a current flight review literally means a flight review, not a check ride or other equivalent activity listed in 61.56?

Comment: A rating checkride can be used in lieu of flight review (i.e. resets the 24 cal month clock) on part 61 for purposes of flying. Question is: does a recent rating qualify as a flight review in terms of getting a UAS certificate via the course rather than taking the knowledge test?